# Distribution of posterior mean from different datasets

Tags: sampling, likelihood, posterior

This question has originated from [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/212722/overestimated-mcmc-standard-deviation-sd).

Suppose we have the following simple setup, for $i = 1, \dots, n$
$$y_i \mid \mu \sim N( \mu, 1) \text{ and } \mu \sim N(0,1). $$

Then due to the nice conjugate setup the posterior distribution for $\mu$ is 
$$\mu \mid \mathbf{y} \sim N\left(\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i}{n+1}, \dfrac{1}{n+1}  \right). $$

Now suppose I do the following $B = 100$ times.

1. Simulate $n = 1000$ from $y \mid \mu$.
2. Draw $r = 2000$ samples from the posterior $X_1, \dots, X_r$ (no need for MCMC).
3. Calculate the posterior mean and posterior standard deviation `est_mu` and `sd_mu`.

So the code for this would look something like.

```
r <- 2000
B <- 100
n <- 1000
est_mu <- numeric(length = B)
sd_mu <- numeric(length = B)
x <- matrix(0, nrow = r, ncol = B)

for(i in 1:B)
{
  # Sampling new data from likelihood
  y <- rnorm(n, mean = 1, sd = 1)

  # Drawing from the posterior
  x[,i] <- rnorm(r, mean = sum(y)/(n+1), sd = sqrt(1/(n+1)))

  est_mu[i] <- mean(x[,i])
  sd_mu[i] <- sd(x[,i])
}
mean(sd_mu)
#[1] 0.03159523
sd(est_mu)
#[1] 0.03150087
```

The value for `mean(sd_mu)` makes sense as it is roughly $\sqrt{1/1001}$, but why is `sd(est_mu)` also roughly the same?

**Question:** How do you show that `sd(est_mu)` $\approx$ `mean(sd_mu)`?

Originally I thought that this was impossible, because the posterior mean for each of $j = 1, \dots B$ draw of the likelihood is
$$\hat{\mu}_j = \dfrac{1}{r} \sum_{t=1}^{r} X_{r} \, \, \text{ where }  X_r \sim \mu \mid Y_j$$

and thus the variance should be $\sigma^2/r$ where $\sigma^2 = Var(\mu|Y) = 1/1001$. But this is clearly not the case as witnessed in the above code.

If however, I use the same data everytime, I get the expected result of the variance being $\sigma^2/r$. So clearly, the randomness in generating the data is getting transferred to the posterior mean estimates and this makes sense intuitively. I am just not able to show it by math.

In addition, the OP on the original comment said that once you have the posterior means from $B = 100$ independent samples, this a just a sample from the posterior distribution, that is, $\hat{\mu}_i \sim \mu|Y$, and I am not able to show this result.

So maybe a more general question is

**Question:** Why is $\hat{\mu}_j \sim \mu|Y$?

Comment: Your R code fails because `object 'r' not found`. It is also unclear why you have `mean = 5`

Comment: Presumably by  $\mu \sim N (0, 1)$ you are referring to a prior rather than a distribution on a higher level of a hierarchical set-up? Is your result just the result of the particular choice of true value of $\mu=5$ that you simulate with? It seems like you had a pretty bad prior...

Comment: For a starters you don't have `mean(est_sd)` anywhere. The standard deviation for $y_i|\mu$ is given. Usually when people want to sample from the posterior they have one set of data $y$, but here you generate 1000 samples which causes some confusion.

Comment: @Henry My bad, I forgot to include `r`. Fixed that. I had set `mean = 5` as a way of setting the truth. I changed it to $\mu = 1$ to address Bjorn's concern

Comment: @Björn Yes, $N(0,1)$ is the prior on $\mu$. I changed the true likelihood so that the prior is not awful.

Comment: @ACE Thanks for pointing that out. I fixed the question and changed `mean(est_sd)` to `mean(sd_mu)`. And yes usually, we have just one data set. But my question originated from the other post where they had done 100 different data sets. This question aims to understand why the posterior means over the 100 datasets will have the same distribution as the posterior.

Comment: I guess there is a gap between my data generation and your understanding. For each MCMC run, I aim to save the point estimate (posterior mean or median) and the standard error of the point estimate (posterior standard deviation). Essentially your question is **why the posterior SD (or the median
absolute deviation, MAD) is a good uncertainty measure (or SE)**. In the package [`rstanarm`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rstanarm/rstanarm.pdf), they use the posterior median as `coef` and MAD as `se`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpret your code as follows:

For $B = 1, 2, \dots 100$

(i) Generate $y \sim N(1_n, I_n)$

(ii) Generate $X \mid y \sim N(1_r [n+1]^{-1}n\bar{y}, [n+1]^{-1}I_r)$

(iii) Compute and store $\bar{X} = 1_r'X/r$

---

(i) and (ii) gives you independent samples from the joint distribution of $(y, X)$. Thus,
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Var}(\bar{X}) &= \mathbb E \mathrm{Var}(\bar{X} \mid y) + \mathrm{Var}(\mathbb E (\bar{X} \mid y))\\
& = \frac{1}{r(n+1)} + \mathrm{Var}\left( \bar{y}\frac{n}{n+1}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{r(n+1)} + \frac{n}{(n+1)^2}.
\end{align}

Thus, the variance of $\bar{X}$ is of the order $1 / (n + 1)$ so you would expect the sample standard deviation over the $B$ runs to estimate its square root fairly well, that is, to about $\sqrt{1/1001}$.

This also shows that the conjecture in the second question is false since, if the distributions of $\bar{X}$ and $X\mid y$ were the same, they would have the same variance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am unclear as to how you got $\frac{\bar{y}n}{n+1}$ as the expectation of $\bar{X}|y$. Shouldn't $E(\bar{X}|y)$ be $\bar{y}$?

Comment: Your code says $X_i \sim N(\sum_i y_i / (n+1), \cdot) = N(\bar{y}n/(n+1), \cdot)$, and then $ \mathbb E \bar{X} = \mathbb E X_i$. Ah, my last edit didn't save. Wait. Now it's probably coherent @Greenparker.

Comment: Oops, sorry, that was stupid of me. Ok as it stands, it makes sense to me. However, I feel like this is an oversimplified version of my problem, since I actually have $y|X = x \sim N(x1_n, I_n)$, and then the same $X|y$ as you.  So my (i) and (ii) does not give the joint distribution of $(y,X)$

Comment: @Greenparker In that case, your code doesn't do what you want it to. Your code does what I've written here (I mean, barring any mistakes on my part). You are generating $y$ with fixed mean in every iteration.

Comment: You are right, the code isn't doing what I thought it was, and so your answer seems correct. Its possible that I have an inadequate understanding of the other question's data generation. I guess for the other question, the statement is false, because the variance for $\bar{X}$ is clearly not the same as the variance for $X$, so the distributions cannot be the same. Thanks!

Comment: @Greenparker Yes, nice observation. Updated with that.